# strongly typed class in my ViewUserControl not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderpartial

I am getting an error in my viewuser control:

Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl'

My viewpage passes the MyViewUserControllerUserList class in the RenderPartial call.

So I am doing:

1. action creates its strongly typed view data, which has a property which is a strongly typed class that my userlist.ascx expects.

userlist.ascx:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyViewUserControllerUserList>"
```

Am I doing this correctly?

**Update**

Just to make sure, my code for my strongly typed partial user control is:

```
 public class MyViewUserControllerUserList: ViewUserControl 
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have looks correct, however you need to make sure the namespace is incuded as well.

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<My.Class.Namespace.ModelClass>"
```

Then you would pass it in like this

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("PartialName", InstanceOfModelClass); %>
```

Then access it inside the partial using the Model property.

Comment: It could be. it could also be a piece of view data that was set in your controller thats not your model. So lets say in your controller you have 

ViewData["PartialModel"] = SomeObject; 

then in your master page, you could call 

<% Html.RenderPartial("PartialName", ViewData["PartialModel"]); %>

In short, you can have any object in your view data be the model of a partial. 

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see ok, I am using strongly typed viewdata in both my model and in the call to my partial. let me investigate arghhh!